# switching ISPs - what do I need to change on the windows server?

Tags: dhcp, windows-server-2000, isp

I have a windows 2000 server that is the domain controller and also the DHCP server for our network.  It is connected to a router.  The router is connected to the connection from the ISP.  The router has been manually configured with IP and DNS servers provided by the ISP.

We are switching ISPs.

Should it be as simple as changing the IP and DNS info in the router?  Would there be anything on the windows server that I need to change?

I'm sorry... I wish we had a sys admin at our company.

Comment: The default gateway will need to be changed on the router, as well as possibly the subnet mask.

Comment: the windows server also acts as the DNS server.  ie.. my workstation points to the windows server for DNS.  Do I need to setup the DNS entries received from my ISP in the windows server somewhere?

Comment: Do you have private addressees on your internal equipment?  You may not to have to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much nailed it from the info you gave.

> Should it be as simple as changing the IP and DNS info in the router?

Yes.